# I Have this headache with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem:

```
function search_by_name($mysql, $name, $lastname)
{
    $query = 'SELECT idKlienci FROM Klienci WHERE Imie = "' . $name . '" 
              AND Nazwisko = "' . $lastnem . '"';
    $result = $mysql->query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // I want to get the ID' of table `Klienci1`
    // and here i don't know how many dimentions have this array
    echo $row[0][0]; // prints nothing
}
```

Comment: Debug your code with `var_dump` or an actual debugger. At the very least inspect the variables you are using.

Comment: are you call the function????

Comment: Check the output on `var_dump($row)` just before `$row[0][0]`

Comment: variables that I'm using are diferent than i wrote, because I'm Polish and I use polisz variable names. i have changed the names so you guys qould understand me better.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["idKlienci"]=> string(1) "1" } 1

Comment: But I have two same names and last names in my database. I did it on purpose.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp . Use `fetch_row` instead of `fetch_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL doesn't use double quotes for strings, it uses simple quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT idKlienci FROM Klienci WHERE Imie = '$name' AND Nazwisko = '$lastname'";
```

You can also add the variable directly into PHP strings when you're using double quotes, without the need to concatenate them.

Comment: He's concatenating outside the string by doing `$a = 'lorem ipsum ' . $dolor . ' sit amet'`, which is perfectly acceptable

Comment: Yes, but the inner string is using double quotes. His query is basically this:          `$query = 'SELECT idKlienci FROM Klienci WHERE Imie = "$name" 
              AND Nazwisko = "$lastnem"';`

Comment: And on mysql, when representing strings, you use a single quote  ' instead of a double quote  "

Answer (score 1):

`$lastnem` != `$lastname`

So change the query to use the correct variable name

```
$query = 'SELECT idKlienci 
            FROM Klienci 
            WHERE Imie = "' . $name . '" 
              AND Nazwisko = "' . $lastname . '"';
```

To make this kind of code easier to read you can also make use of the fact that variables in a double quoted string are automatically expanded. Which make this easier to read and therefore debug.

```
$query = "SELECT idKlienci 
            FROM Klienci 
            WHERE Imie = '$name' 
              AND Nazwisko = '$lastname'";

$result = $mysql->query($query);

// use mysqli_fetch_assoc() then you get only one assoc array
// so you can use named parameters to the array.
// the names will match the column names in the table

//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
// also mysqli_fetch_assoc() only returns one row at a time
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// a row is always one dimensional so do 
echo $row['id'];
```

So if you have more than one row in the resultset of your query you have to get the results in a loop

```
$result = $mysql->query($query);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo $row['id'] . '<br>'; 
}
```

Now you should see both rows

Comment: See my amended answer, about your other issue

Comment: Yes, but how to move around the rows??

Comment: I have amended my answer again

Comment: the variable names are only for you guys in my script everything matches ine teh name space

Comment: Please remember we can only comment on what we see in your question. If you accidentally add errors by not copy/pasting the real code we are going to assume if we see an error _its an error_

Comment: THAT SOLVED MY HEADACHE. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Your Argument name `$lastname` & used variable `$lastnem` name are not same.

Comment: Thats why 'Nazwisko' get undefined value.

Comment: It is the same in my script I am using polish names but not characters

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    echo $row[0];
```

Comment: prints on the screen : 1

Comment: If i use echo $row[0]; prints noting

Comment: sorry $row[1]; prints nothing

Comment: try print_r($row);